# Why are questions moved to SuperUser?

Tags: support, questions

For the last few days now, I've seen some questions either closed or moved to SuperUser.

Why is that?

Comment: because it's non-programming questions

Comment: Ironic that a question about migration is migrated? Awesome!

Answer (score 6):

Because SuperUser is for questions that are from a general hardware or software perspective. Many people will mistakenly think that StackOverflow is going to help them with making their computer work, so we will migrate it to our other site.

Also, ServerFault exists for questions that are more networking and SysAdmin related.

Comment: Should be specified that home networking belongs on SU, for realsies networking belongs on SF.

Comment: That's why I included "SysAdmin related".

Comment: @TheTXI: Yes, but I wanted to use the term "for realsies networking" for the Google spider.

Comment: (fwiw, *no one* is going to Google "for realsies networking")

Comment: @Jonik: I was planning to a minute ago. Now I'm planning to write a script to do it every 3 minutes instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the sites each have a different content and audience focus. See the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is related to a computer hardware or software in general then they belong to superuser.com